# Python character with hex value

Tags: python

Python have an escape sequence in which \x is there and if we write two integers after \x and print it, it gives us a character for e.g- `print("\x48")` gives us letter H. I want a list that shows which number is assigned to which character.

The hexadecimal numbers 48 and 46 are assigned to H and F respectively:

```
print("\x48")
print("\x46")
```

I want list of all numbers that are assigned to their respective character.

Comment: https://www.asciitable.com

Comment: what you are presenting is bytes presented as hex bytes. the table you are looking for is called the Ascii table and you can get some info over here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ASCII

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Use `hex` and `chr`

```
print("Dec Hex Char")
for c in range(32,127):
    print(c, hex(c), chr(c))
```

Output is:

```
Dec Hex Char
32 0x20  
33 0x21 !
34 0x22 "
35 0x23 #
36 0x24 $
37 0x25 %
38 0x26 &
39 0x27 '
40 0x28 (
41 0x29 )
42 0x2a *
43 0x2b +
44 0x2c ,
45 0x2d -
46 0x2e .
47 0x2f /
48 0x30 0
```

etc, to

```
119 0x77 w
120 0x78 x
121 0x79 y
122 0x7a z
123 0x7b {
124 0x7c |
125 0x7d }
126 0x7e ~
```